# How to make that multiply all numbers in list (Permutation) with smaller code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

My problem is:

```
    perm_list = list(range(a,b,-1))
    if len(perm_list) == 1:
       print(perm_list[0])
    elif len(perm_list) == 2:
       print(perm_list[0]* perm_list[1])
    elif len(perm_list) == 3:
```

I cant find a way to make that smaller if i can do it would be awesome.
Because i will do that to 15, If i write that 15 times it will be bigger and more hard to write for me.
  If there is a smaller was to make that can you guys please tell me?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. Your code isn't very clear. You haven't provided enough of an example to understand what you're trying to do. What would the 15th `elif` look like?

Comment: I am trying to make a permutation like you will put 2 numbers P(a.b)

Comment: And the max number is 15

Comment: if you put 15 and 2 it will be p(15,2) and it should be 15.14

Comment: Looks like you're simply multiplying all the items in the list?

Comment: Yes, making a list with range For example range(a,b,-1) to take len if user gives a = 5 and b = 3 list will be 5.4.3 but problem is i dont know what is b so i stuck

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `itertools` library

```
from itertools import permutations
lst = list(range(3))
result = list(permutations(lst, 2))
print(result)
=> [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
print(list(permutations(lst, 3)))
=>  [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
```